# Rank-one updates for symmetric matrix eigen-system

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, lapack, update

Are there existing implementations for rank-one updating of symmetric matrices eigensystems?
This is the mathematical statement of the problem. Let $S=QDQ^T$
$$S + vv^T = QDQ^T +vv^T = Q_{new}D_{new}Q_{new}^T$$
This [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/80968) describes the algorithm for efficiently computing update, but the closest thing I found was [SLAED7](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d24/group__aux_o_t_h_e_rcomputational_gaa82b498880b501e765256dcabb001dd8.html) in LAPACK, which assumes S is tridiagonal symmetric.